# CLion isn't updating the Xcode path when changing path with xcode-select

Tags: c++, path, xcode-select

I recently changed Xcode paths from my external hard drive to my internal hard drive and now CLion is giving me some IntelliSense errors for `std::` stuff.

I've tried restarting my computer and CLion itself and I have gone through basically every setting but I can't find a way to stop the errors.

Before I changed path (external -> internal) it was fine, after I changed it though, it broke.

Here is what I'm seeing:

[image: random and fstream are underlined in red]

[image: random_device, mt19937_64, uniform_int_distribution<> and distr are underlined in red/is red]

[image: ios is red]

I can still build my project perfectly using cmake/make, but CLion still has red/underlined text.

Answer (score 2):

After editing my Makefile with a bunch of random letters, and pressing Reload project and then deleting the random letters and reloading the project, it told me that the cache was corrupted.

It then gave me an option to fix the cache and now, after a restart of the IDE, everything works properly! If you want an easy way to reload your Makefile project, go to Tools > Makefile > Reload Makefile Project.